# How to return a String from an if block which is inside a for loop?

Tags: java, string, foreach, return

I want to return a substring which i try to extract from the string based on the starting word.

Why do I always get a null when i invoke this method instead of a string.

private static String parse(String response, String startRule, String endRule) {

```
String arrayResponse[]=response.split(".+");
String output = null;
    for(String element:arrayResponse) {
        if(element.startsWith(startRule)) {
             output= element.substring(startRule.length()-1,element.indexOf(endRule));  
            break;
        }
    }
    return output;  
}
```

Comment: what does your `split` return? An empty array?

Comment: The regex `.+` will match the whole string. So, the whole string will be seen as separator and your result array will be empty.

Comment: my guess is that your if statement is false (try it separately), or give here an example of code you used to test your function

Answer (score 0):

With `.+`, you're splitting the *response* on any character, 1 or more.

You'll want to use a space,  `+`.

```java
String arrayResponse[]=response.split(" +");
```